# Bubblewrap Build fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, bubblewrap

I am trying to use Bubblewrap to ship my PWA as an android app. I have installed the latest @bubblewrap/cli, JDK 11 and Android SDK Android Studio

More details about my Android SDK version:
Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292, built on October 1, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.

Operating System: macOS 10.14.5

When I try to run the bubblewrap build command, it fails with the below error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRj1e.png)

I tried every possible solutions like pointing the same JDK in my Android SDK, installing the Android CLI in the SDK managers, reinstalling the bubblewrap cli. Nothing works.

Any pointers will help!